# Pull data from other tables even if that data isnt present

Tags: crystal-reports

What I'm trying to do is pull all the data from one table and then if the data is available in another table then pull that field also if not just display N/A.

for example i have a table of order information

```
product code, description,qty ect
```

and then i have a table for the picking list

```
(primary key)picking list number
```

but a order has to be accepted before a picking list number is created. so i want to display all the information in the order table and then if they is a picking list number display that if not just display N/A.

Just wondered if thats possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left Outer Join... should list all items from "left" table, and those matching join conditions from the right.

Remember that any conditions in the Record Selection work on all records -- If you're not careful, using a field from the "right" table in your selection can turn the query into an INNER query.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't stand it any longer... an explanation of the LOJ / "conditions" comment.

You have the "ON" condition that is part of the LOJ.
You also have the "WHERE" conditions that are part of the whole query.

There is a big difference between

```
SELECT 
   PERSONS_NAME,
   PERSONS_ADDRESS,
   PERSONS_CITY, 
   PERSONS_STATE
FROM
  MYRECORDS MR
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      MYDETAILS MD
        ON  MR.MYID = MD.MYID
WHERE
   NOT PERSONS_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
   AND
   (some other wx clauses)
```

and

```
SELECT 
   PERSONS_NAME,
   PERSONS_ADDRESS,
   PERSONS_CITY, 
   PERSONS_STATE
FROM
  MYRECORDS MR
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      MYDETAILS MD
        ON  MR.MYID = MD.MYID  
            AND   
            NOT PERSONS_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
WHERE
   (some other wx clauses)
```

The first will give you ONLY records where ADDRESS exists... skipping records where just the PERSONS_NAME exists.

The second will give you ALL PERSONS_NAMEs, but will INCLUDE address information when PERSONS_ADDRESS exists.

It's a poor example above, but it illustrates the issue:

If you are using a field in the RIGHT TABLE in the WHERE clause, the LOJ becomes the equivalent of an INNER JOIN -- losing the value of LOJs.

If you add the condition into the ON clause, the LOJ operates AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but still keeps the ability to include SELECTED records from the RIGHT TABLE.

Sorry for all of the CAPPED words, but it's late, my vision is bleary, and I wanted to STRESS something or other.  I forget now.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, short of using a command, Crystal Reports won't support the ON kind. Best bet is to either command or use stored procedures to fetch your data.